# The left expression of the compound assignment is an uninitialized value. The computed value will also be garbage

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

When I run the build for my iOS project it throws a logic error: *The left expression of the compound assignment is an uninitialized value. The computed value will also be garbage.*

This is being thrown in the Yoga package that can be found [here](https://github.com/facebook/yoga/blob/master/yoga/Yoga.h).

I checked out different Stack Overflow and Github threads but I couldn't find anyone with the same issue.

```
(performLayout ? layoutMarkerData.cachedLayouts
                   : layoutMarkerData.cachedMeasures) += 1;
```

This should build without this error.

Comment: Does postfix `++` work?  Otherwise split the lines up - it's not an obfuscation competition.

Comment: Neither of these solutions worked. Xcode throws the logic error ```+ is a garbage value``` when I expanded it.

Comment: So `if (performLayout) layoutMarkerData.cachedLayouts++; else layoutMarkerData.cachedMeasures++;` failed?

Comment: @OneManMonkeySquad that was an unnecessary and pointless comment. If you clicked the link you can see that Xcode is complaining about Yoga which is a cross-platform layout engine that implements Flexbox. I didn't create it Facebook did and I am just using it.

Comment: @trojanfoe yes it failed.

Comment: OK show their declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used Yoga before but my best guess from the error would be that it's trying to increment uninitialised memory, based on **layoutMarkerData** appearing to be an instance of [Layout Data](https://github.com/facebook/yoga/blob/90cded3819bb9849d0cfeaab05e811bfe6645c1c/yoga/event/event.h#L39):

```
struct LayoutData {
    int layouts;
    int measures;
    int maxMeasureCache;
    int cachedLayouts;
    int cachedMeasures;
    int measureCallbacks;
    std::array<int, static_cast<uint8_t>(LayoutPassReason::COUNT)>
    measureCallbackReasonsCount;
};
```

**cachedLayouts** and **cachedMeasures** are both ints that aren't given a default value so if LayoutData is [default initialised](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) they have the value of whatever was in memory a.k.a garbage.

So I would guess the fix is to assign them a value before the line you've supplied.